# Few days ago I started learning Java - please explain this errror

Tags: java, error-handling

Please explain this error:

```
[
    {
        "resource": "/C:/Users/shubh/OneDrive/Desktop/Array/ArrayCC.java",
        "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
        "code": "536871799",
        "severity": 4,
        "message": "Resource leak: ***'sc' is never closed"***,
        "source": "Java",
        "startLineNumber": 11,
        "startColumn": 17,
        "endLineNumber": 11,
        "endColumn": 19
    }
]
```

I want to clear my doubt

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Some honest feedback: The title of your question is not good. Nobody will find this from a search engine, and even if it is seen, it is not likely to be clicked. The content of your question is not good either, as you do not describe your problem, nor do you explain what you've tried, where exactly you are stuck, etc. When authoring a question here, please imagine you are an author writing for for other people who may one day encounter the same issue you are having. Then your questions will be better received, and more likely to attract answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that `sc` refers to a `Scanner`.

`Scanners` should be closed when no longer needed.

Example:

```
sc.close();
```